# How to precalculate expensive Expressions in Polars (in groupby-s and in general)?

Tags: python-polars

I'm having a hard time dealing with the fact that in a `groupby` I cant efficiently catch a group sub-dataframe with an `Expr`, perform an expensive operation with it **once** and then return several different aggregations. I can sort of do it (see example), but my solution is unreadable and looks like Im dealing with an unnecessary overhead because of all those lists. Is there a proper or a completely different way to do it?

Take a look at this example:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000000, 3)))
expensive = pl.col('column_1').cumprod().ewm_std(span=10).alias('expensive')
```

```py
%%timeit
(
df
.groupby('column_0')
.agg([
    expensive.sum().alias('sum'),
    expensive.median().alias('median'),
    *[expensive.max().alias(f'max{x}') for x in range(10)],
    
])
)
```

> 417 ms ± 38.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```py
%%timeit
(
    df
    .groupby('column_0')
    .agg(expensive)
    .select([
        pl.col('expensive').arr.eval(pl.element().sum()).arr.first().alias('sum'),
        pl.col('expensive').arr.eval(pl.element().median()).arr.first().alias('median'),
        *[pl.col('expensive').arr.eval(pl.element().max()).arr.first().alias(f'max{x}') for x in range(10)]
    ])
)
```

> 95.5 ms ± 9.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

We can see that precomputing the `expensive` part is beneficial, but actually doing it involves this `.arr.eval(pl.element().<aggfunc>()).arr.first()` that really bothers me because of both readability and flexibility. Try as I might, I cant see a better solution.

I'm not sure whether the problem is just about `groupby`s, if your solution involves dealing with `select`s, please share that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` instead of `arr.eval` like this:

```
%%timeit
df \
    .groupby('column_0') \
    .agg(expensive).explode('expensive').groupby('column_0').agg([
        pl.col('expensive').sum().alias('sum'),
        pl.col('expensive').median().alias('median'),
        *[pl.col('expensive').max().alias(f'max{x}') for x in range(10)]
    ])
```

On my machine the run times were

Your first example: `320 ms ± 18.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Your second: `80.8 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Mine: `63 ms ± 507 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Another method which turns out to be slightly slower than the above is to do the `expensive` expression has a window function which then skips the `explode`

```
%%timeit
df.select(['column_0',expensive.over('column_0')]).groupby('column_0').agg([
        pl.col('expensive').sum().alias('sum'),
        pl.col('expensive').median().alias('median'),
        *[pl.col('expensive').max().alias(f'max{x}') for x in range(10)]
    ])
```

This last one returned in `69.7 ms ± 911 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`